# Pre-load value into field in symfony form, getting error "Cannot Update form fields"

Tags: php, forms, symfony1, doctrine, relational-database

I have a form that is supposed to create a very simple new entry into the database. One of the fields in this table is related to another table. Specifically, there is an event that people attend, and I need to assign people to an event. Each event can have several people attending, and there can be several events.

When an admin user adds members to an event, I don't need them selecting the event on the actual form, this should be passed via the URL. e.g.
`event/new/id/1`

However, I am really struggling as to how to include that ID in the form. If I try and manually set the field value, I get the error `Cannot Update Form Fields`
e.g.

```
    $this->['attendanceSuccess_id'] = 1;
```

If I try and hide the field:

```
    
$this->widgetSchema['attendanceSuccess_id'] = new sfWidgetFormInputHidden();
```

The form shows but obviously no value is passed and I get "that fields is required error"

This seems like a really simple and common thing to do, but I can't find any solutions! How can I pass a URL value into a form where the field points to another class?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've done. Basically your form holds a hidden with the id, and your action gets it from the request and puts in into the form as an option. In the form you can also set the relationship to the Doctrine objects.

Your form should have something like (I don't know what your form should extend exactly since you are using Doctrine and mine was in Propel)

```
class SomethingForm extends BaseSomethingForm {

public function __construct($object = null, $options = array(), $CSRFSecret = null)
{
    parent::__construct($object, $options, $CSRFSecret);
    if (isset($options['person_id']))
    {
        $this->getObject()->setPersonId($options['person_id']);
        $this->setDefault('person_id', $options['person_id']);
    }

}
}

public function configure()
{
    $this->setWidget('person_id', new sfWidgetFormInputHidden());
...more stuff...
}
```

Then your action says:

```
$this->form = new SomethingForm(null, array(
'person_id' => $request->getParameter('person_id')
));
```

Comment: Why do you override constructor for this?

Comment: Originally I did it because it was a required option (person_id, for instance), and I threw an Exception if it wasn't there (but I excised that part of the code when pasting it in). My form had to have that option to work properly, so I wanted it in the constructor, to ensure that the form could not exist without that option. In other places, I've also done it with a setter which I use in the action like `$this->form->setPersonId($request->getParameter('person_id'))`. Do you have a preference? Either way seems good to me, depending on how vital the option is, and how clean the code looks.